# What is the difference between Excel NumberFormat and NumberFormatLocal?

Tags: c++, asp.net, excel

As the Title says, I have read the documentation and tried in c++ code using a Swedish locale, but I don't get it. What is the difference between these two properties?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.numberformat.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.numberformatlocal.aspx

Comment: This is just a guess, but in the example, the `NumberFormat` is `m/d/yyyy` and `NumberFormatLocal` is probably different if the user's language is set to something where the words for "month," "day" and "year" do not start with "m," "d" and "y" respectively.

Comment: I should probably have elaborated my question. The thing is that NumberFormat() doesn't work as documented, at least not when called from a Swedish locale.

From the documentation, I got the impression that "NumberFormat" would always accept US format symbols, while NumberFormatLocale accepts localized formatting charcaters -- such as for example 'J' instead of 'Y' for year in Germany.

But when I use Range->SetNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"), it outputs "yyyy-52-31", interpreting yyyy as unknown, mm as minutes and dd as days -- as if I had called SetNumberFormatLocale. Hence my question.